# PHP ticketing system + vBulletin

Tags: php, vbulletin, ticket-system

Is there a good php ticketing system such as kayako eSupport and DeskPro that integrates with vBulletin nicely?

Kayako and DeskPro are too costly for the business at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read some stuff in the past about [OTRS](http://otrs.org/index/), might look into that. Also a quick Google search found these:

- [OSTicket](http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=949)
- [SimpleTicket](http://www.simpleticket.net/)